# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'E:\client\index.html'

Tags: node.js, api, http

i'm trying to send a http method from a service on angular to that an api on nodejs to it do the petition to server but appear this error:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'E:\client\index.html'
```

this is my code:

```
//rutas
app.use('/', express.static('client', {redirect:false}));
app.use('/api', insumos_routes);

app.get('*', function(req, res, next){
     res.sendFile(path.resolve('/client/index.html'));   
});

//export
module.exports= app;
```

already try this:

```
res.sendFile('/client/index.html');   
res.sendFile('./index.html');
```

...like it say others answers

Comment: can you provide a full directory structure for the project?

Answer (score 0):

`path.resolve` takes two or more arguments if it's to be useful. You need to give it a base path.

For example:

```
path.resolve(__dirname, 'client/index.html');
```

Where you want that path to be *relative to* the directory your script is in.

Comment: Where is that file relative to your script? You may need to adjust this by navigating using `'../client/index.html'` and so on.

Comment: i have this file in client/src/index.html but already typed it and doesn't work

Comment: You need to explain where this file is in relation to the script above. If it's in `client/src/index.html` then `client/index.html` has zero hope of finding it since `src/` is a necessary path component.

Comment: ...yes i put the route correct with src, but this error only pass with delete method and when i use the browser, it doesn't pass with postman client

Comment: yes, i put the correct path with  src but doesn't work, this only pass when i put this route on de browser, when i use postman it work

Comment: Instead of saying "doesn't work" can you try and confirm that the `path.resolve(...)` output is correct and that you're not getting any other informational errors?